# Using CASE in MySQL setting value to NULL or blank

Tags: mysql

Can I set the value to blank in a MySQL CASE? Such as this;

```
...
    SELECT ID, subNet,
    CASE
    WHEN subNet = 0 THEN ''
    ...
```

The value always shows 0 instead of going blank. I also tried IS NULL and just NULL like this;
 ...THEN '', and again like this THEN subNet = ''

I don't want to see anything for the value if subNet is 0

Comment: Please post reproducible case with table structure, sample data and full query for example by using https://dbfiddle.uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can....  works just fine.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
    (`id` int, `subnet` int)
;

INSERT INTO tbl
    (`id`, `subnet`)
VALUES
    (1, 0),
    (2, 27),
    (3, 50),
    (4, 2)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
    SELECT id, 
            subnet,
            CASE WHEN subnet = 0 THEN ''
                 ELSE subnet
                 END subnet_suppressed_0
      FROM tbl
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb8106/1/0)**:

```
| id | subnet | subnet_suppressed_0 |
|----|--------|---------------------|
|  1 |      0 |                     |
|  2 |     27 |                  27 |
|  3 |     50 |                  50 |
|  4 |      2 |                   2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do was just to test the value in PHP and recode it there.